# filemanager-actions with Hyper 20.04

Tags: nautilus

So I want there to be a context menu action to open [Hyper](https://hyper.is) in the current directory, so I set up the menu and it works perfectly except for one small thing: `%d` isn't directed to the current directory. If I use the action in `~/Projects/Candola` it opens Hyper in `~/Projects`, and if used in `~` it goes to `/home`. Is there any other variable I missed that allows this to be fixed?

[Action tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrfLE.png)
[Command tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7QwC.png)

Comment: How did you set up the menu? Provide details because the error could be there.

Comment: Thank you @vanadium, totally forgot to do that! Updated with that information

Comment: Still no idea. Is this nautilus actions? Anyway, others may see more clear. Be aware that filemanager-actions is not anymore available in 20.10, so this may not anymore be an option in the future.